# wifiManager.startScan not returning any results (need some guidance please)

Tags: android, eclipse, wifimanager

At this moment in time I am trying to build an Android application that will be able to locate a wifi enabled device indoors. So I have broken it down into various steps in order and 1 of the steps is to scan for available wireless networks and return the signal strength etc associated with each access point that it discovers (it doesn't have to connect to the access points but just has to ping them for information). Below shows the  snippet of code that I have created and when the code is debugged it isn't identifying an wifi access points so could someone tell me where the problem is or point me in the right direction.

```
myWifiMan.startScan();
List<ScanResult> wifiList = myWifiMan.getScanResults();
if (wifiList != null) {
    //Construct Clue
    for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++) {
        message = message + "'" + wifiList.get(i).SSID +"':" + Integer.toString(wifiList.get(i).level);
        if((i+1) < wifiList.size())
        message = message + ",";
    }
    message = message + "}]";
```

due to the answer given below would the following code give me the desired results?

```
private void initializeWiFiListener(){

    System.out.println("executing initializeWiFiListener");
    String connectivity_context = Context.WIFI_SERVICE;
    final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(connectivity_context);
    if(!wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
        if(wifi.getWifiState() != WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING){
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }

    }
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {             
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            boolean a= wifiManager.startScan();//request a scan for access points
            final List<ScanResult> results= wifiManager.getScanResults();//list of access points from the last scan
                for(final ScanResult result : results){
                System.out.println("ScanResult level: "+ result.level);
            }               
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's probably because the [`startScan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startScan%28%29) method only triggers the discovery of the nearby access points, and doesn't make them available to you immediatly.

The Android documentation states about this method that it :

> Request a scan for access points. Returns immediately. The
>   availability of the results is made known *later* by means of an
>   *asynchronous* event sent on completion of the scan.

So, you'd have to register a `BroadcastReceiver` to the [`SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION) in order to get the list of the available access points as soon as the scan completes.

At this time, you can call the [`getScanResults()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults%28%29) method which will return the list of the found access points.

**EDIT :** Also make sure that the Wi-Fi is enabled on the device before launching a scan.

Comment: I would not declare my `BroadcastReceiver` as an anonymous class, as I may want to unregister it when I'm done with it. Also turning the Wi-Fi on seems intrusive and requires an additional permission. I would ask the user to turn it on explicitely.

Comment: I am having this problem on the broadcastreceiver that gets the SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION on a Moto X 2nd device (2014). Basically, I can see the scans on the system's UI, but can't reach them on my app. I am using the required permissions, and this behavior doesn't occur in other devices (S6, Nexus 5...).

Comment: @leRobot I have posted an answer. I think it will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

For getScanResults, the official android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults%28%29) says -

> An app must hold ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in order to get valid results.

I had the same problem. Without these permissions, my code was working in Samsung phones but not in Nexus or Motorola. After enabling these permissions it gives more appropriate results and works in all the phones.