# Why the list is always empty?

Tags: java, android

in this code i am searching the wifi access points and showing the results in text view.... it works fine on samsung phone but for some reason the list is always empty in case of other phones....

can you help me understand why the list is always empty? I ll be very grateful.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Switch aswitch;
    int n=1;
    TextView text;
    WifiManager wifi;
    String message;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        aswitch=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.myswitch);
        wifi=(WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytv);

        aswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // do something, the isChecked will be
                // true if the switch is in the On position
                if (isChecked && !wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    message="enabled";
                    text.setText(message);


                } else if (!isChecked && wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    message="disabled";
                    text.setText(message);
                }
            }
        });

            MyBroadcastReceiver broadcast=new MyBroadcastReceiver();
            registerReceiver(broadcast, new IntentFilter(wifi.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));



    }
    class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            StringBuffer stringBuffer=new StringBuffer();
            List<ScanResult> list=wifi.getScanResults();

            for(ScanResult scanResult:list){
                String ssid0 = scanResult.SSID;
                int rssi0 = scanResult.level;
                String rssiString0 = String.valueOf(rssi0);
                stringBuffer.append("\n SSID:" + ssid0 + "   RSSI:" + rssiString0 +"dBm");
                text.setText("yes");
            }
            text.setText(stringBuffer);
            if(wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
                wifi.startScan();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `startScan()` is asynchronous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wifiManager.startScan not returning any results (need some guidance please)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686033/wifimanager-startscan-not-returning-any-results-need-some-guidance-please)

Comment: followed the link...still list is empty

Answer (score 0):

As strange as it looks You must declare a fine or coarse location permission in manifest. Had this problem myself some time ago.

Comment: i have added these permissions still the list is empty.

Comment: if you are testing on a device with api 23+ please check that those permissions are granted.

Comment: i have granted the permission from user input still the list is empty....is there anything else i should do?